# Two sample T test ploting problems

Tags: r

I have been using a CVS file as a data frame to conduct some T test analysis and wishing to plot the results. However, I keep getting the error message. Does anyone have any ideas why it is not working?

```
> test1<- t.test(Cetinje$Ocjena.govora.Ocjena.govora..Pitanje.8.~ Cetinje$Pol.Identitet,alternative="two.sided",conf.level=0.95)
> test1

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Cetinje$Ocjena.govora.Ocjena.govora..Pitanje.8. by Cetinje$Pol.Identitet
t = -3.665, df = 25.134, p-value = 0.001157
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.6018368 -0.4494452
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
       2.307692        3.333333 

plot(test1)

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Comment: I don’t think the result of a `t.test` can be plotted. What made you think it would? What output would you expect (not to say that it’s inconceivable, just that it’s not entirely clear)? — Worse, the result of `t.test` holds no reference to its original data (unlike, say, `lm`), so it fundamentally **cannot** be plotted (at least not with reference to the original data, for example as a box plot).

Comment: Basically I want the same as box plot, but box plot gives me variance and median of the groups, what I want is the variance and mean of the groups (since T test is testing for that). Found some tutorials online that made me think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
boxplot(Cetinje$Ocjena.govora.Ocjena.govora..Pitanje.8.~ Cetinje$Pol.Identitet)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer mentioned, you simply use the `boxplot` function. You can additionally mark significant differences with a simple trick:

```
# Significance thresholds
alpha = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001)
symbols = c('***', '**', '*', '')
which_symbol = as.numeric(cut(test1$p.value, c(0, rev(alpha), 1)))

boxplot(Cetinje$Ocjena.govora.Ocjena.govora..Pitanje.8.~ Cetinje$Pol.Identitet)

ypos = max(Cetinje$Ocjena.govora.Ocjena.govora..Pitanje.8.[Cetinje$Pol.Identitet == levels(Cetinje$Pol.Identitet)[2]])
text(x = 2, y = ypos, symbols[which_symbol], cex = 1.5, adj = c(0.5, 0))
```

Incidentally, the code shows that good variable names are imperative; the second-to-last line is neigh unreadable. It would be vastly improved by better variable names.